# Behavior of entityManager when using SpringDataJpa with Hibernate/eclipselink

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, eclipselink

I want to use a mix of SpringDataJpa and Eclipselink/Hibernate for persistence in my application. Till now, I have come across an approach detailed [here](https://dzone.com/articles/accessing-the-entitymanager-from-spring-data-jpa). What I want to is use Spring Data JPARepository for CRUD operations and use a conventional @Repository bean for more complex queries or other functionality. It is important that I ensure the same entityManager is used for both, the usual method calls to the @Repository class and calls to the spring JpaRepository interface (class generated by spring).

My setup is done as in the example given [here](https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-part-one-configuration/).

Comment: As I understand you want to write custom queries, right? If yes you can create repository implementation for customization. Here is the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations

Comment: @pepuch thanks for your reply. Yeah, if I can't get the scenario I am looking for, I am going to go with the approach described in the link you shared. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Don't.

Why would you split the repository bean in two (from the perspective of the user of the repository). You can have custom methods in your repository of which you completely control the implementation.

If you really want to you can always inject an `EntityManager` in other classes and if they participate in the same transaction (and you don't have some really weird setup) you will using the same single `EntityManager` in all places.

Comment: Hi Jens. Thanks for your answer. My intention is not to split the repository bean into two. What I want to do is:

1. Use my interface to extend JpaRepository and let all simple queries that deal with one entity go through that and in the process leverage the auto query generation it provides.

2. Have a separate class that has nothing to do with Spring Data Jpa and is basically a jpa implementation like eclipselink/hibernate and I want to use this for native queries and complex join queries. 
All I want is to be able to use Spring Data Jpa's entityManager.

Comment: I think I understood that. What I don't understand is why you don't bundle it into one thing by using Spring Data's support for custom method implementations. But I also don't have to understand everything ;-)

Comment: No no I totally get your point but I kind of need to use this approach as of now. If I absolutely cannot do it, I will move on with Spring Data Jpa and let it do all the dao stuff. Will probably just configure it with hibernate. Thanks.